# Combining two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array `ar1` with dimensions (1196, 14, 64, 1).

I have a numpy array `ar2` with dimensions (1196,).

I want to combine these two because I want to shuffle them later. I thought that this was the kind of thing that zip was made for, but when I zip them together:

`ar3 = np.asarray(zip(ar1,ar2))`

then `print(ar3.shape)` gives `()`

I have also tried `np.concatenate` but apparently `all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly`.

I tried `np.hstack` but I got `all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`

How can I combine these two arrays that have the same size along axis 0? Perhaps I don't need to combine then and should just shuffle them separately using the same indices.

(I already actually combined and saved these arrays using numpy.savez, but when I load this file into my code, I assume that I have to separate them first and then recombine the in an array as I am trying to do. If I could just pull out a combines array from the .npz file then that would be even better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) along with [`np.broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html), because concatenate needs all the arrays to have the same number of dimensions. This should do the trick:

```py
x = np.ones((1196, 14, 64, 1))
y = np.arange(1196)
output = np.concatenate((x, np.broadcast_to(y[:, None, None, None], x.shape[:-1] + (1,))), axis=-1)
# output.shape --> (1196, 14, 64, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [111]: ar1 = np.ones((1196,14,62,1))                                                              
In [112]: ar2 = np.zeros((1196))
```

In py3, `zip` is generator-like.  You have expand it with `list` to get an array:

```
In [113]: np.array(zip(ar1,ar2))                                                                     
Out[113]: array(<zip object at 0x7f188a465a48>, dtype=object)
```

That's a single element array, with shape ().

If you expand the zip, and make an array, the result is a object dtype array:

```
In [119]: A = np.array(list(zip(ar1,ar2)))                                                           
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  #!/usr/bin/python3
In [120]: A.shape                                                                                    
Out[120]: (1196, 2)
In [121]: A.dtype                                                                                    
Out[121]: dtype('O')
In [122]: A[0,0].shape                                                                               
Out[122]: (14, 62, 1)
In [123]: A[0,1].shape                                                                               
Out[123]: ()
```

One column is the (14,62,1) arrays, the other the `ar2` values.

The other answer suggests expanding `ar2` to match `ar1` in shape, and concatenating on the last axis.  The result is twice the size of `ar1`.  `broadcast_to` does a 'virtual' replication (no increase in memory), but that doesn't carry over in the concatenate.  You get 14*62 copies of every `ar2` value.

But `ar2` could be broadcast to (1196,1,62,1) and concatenate on axis 1 (a 62x replication), or (1196,14,1,1) and axis 2 concatenate (14x).  To concatenate, the arrays have to match on all but one axis.

But for `savez` and `load` you don't need to concatenate the arrays.  You can save and load them separately.  `savez` puts them in separate `npy` files.  `savez` shows how to load each array.

And you can shuffle them separately.

Make a shuffling index:

```
In [124]: idx = np.arange(1196)                                                                      
In [125]: np.random.shuffle(idx)                                                                     
In [126]: idx[:10]                                                                                   
Out[126]: array([ 561,  980,   42,   98, 1055,  375,   13,  771,  832,  787])
```

and apply it to each array:

```
In [127]: ar1[idx,:,:,:];                                                                            
In [128]: ar2[idx];
```